# Autogenerated Java ee-application does not connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, netbeans

I have created a web-application with NetBeans 11.2. This IDE can automatically generate java-classes from DB-tables. I tried to use this feature and got files `Clients.java`, `ClientsController.java` and `ClientsFacade.java` from the table `CLIENTS` of my database, that runs on local PostgreSQL server. These java files intended to add, delete records to and from table, to list records etc., I've got it, that's OK.

The `ClientsFacade.java` looks like this:

```java
package com.simplebank.web;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class ClientsFacade extends AbstractFacade<Clients> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my_persistence_unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ClientsFacade() {
        super(Clients.class);
    }
    
}
```

The parameter `"my_persistence_unit"` points to some JDBC-connection, as far as I understand. I have found  in my project the `persistence.xml` file, in which this parameter also mentioned, and have edited it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
  <!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
  <persistence-unit name="my_persistence_unit">
    <class>com.simplebank.web.Accounts</class>
    <class>com.simplebank.web.Clients</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="student"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="some-password"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

All parameters of JDBC-connection are correct, I guarantee this. But after building the project I tried to open the facelet `clients/List.xhtml` in my GlassFish server, and got the error message:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:728)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:678)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4576)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2084)

...

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'STUDENT' does not exist
Error Code: 30000
Call: SELECT id AS a1, family AS a2, name AS a3, pass_number AS a4, pass_series AS a5 FROM clients OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY 
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Clients sql="SELECT id AS a1, family AS a2, name AS a3, pass_number AS a4, pass_series AS a5 FROM clients OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY ")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:482)
    at com.simplebank.www.AbstractFacade.findRange(AbstractFacade.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

...
```

One more time: the schema STUDENT does(!) exists. I can see it and all the tables within it with `psql` utility (`PGPASSWORD="blah-blah" psql -U student`). Also I have wrote  simple java-program, that connects to the DB with traditional way (JDBC-driver) and it works fine. Moreover, when GlassFish server starts, I see the line in debug area:

```
" EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a|#]
  /file:/home/3f-lab/_ide/NETBEANS/web/target/web-1.0/WEB-INF/classes/_my_persistence_unit login successful|#]"
```

But facelet does not work. Please explain me what do I wrong.

Comment: check whether the database name given in jdbc url is correct and also to check whether that student table is in some other schema (rather than in public schema as postgresql database is used)

Comment: Is the URL absolutely correct? `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student`. Right now "student" is both the schema name and the table name. It's strange to have a schema name like this. Generally this has a bit more general name such as "companyname" or "default". Try URL of `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432` instead. This is not a JSF problem at all so I've removed the JSF tag.

Comment: @BalusC: the `student` in the URL refers to a **database** with that name, not a schema.

Comment: "*All parameters of JDBC-connection are correct, I guarantee this*" - so you created a **database** with the name `student`?

Comment: Guys, I tried many different names for database, schema and user. For example, in the begining db was named `bank`, schema `public` and user `student`. The result regardless of such names always was the same: connection works via simple `JDBC` and via `psql` utility, but does not work in GlassFish. Finally I have named all three parameters (db, use and schema) `student` for simplicity (and Postgres contains relevent objects), but the error appears again.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by myself. The cause was (IMHO) in default connection pool, that was set in GlassFish (or in NetBeans?) as DerbyDB connection. I have added new connection pool, related to my PostgreSQL database, change default in GlassFish admin console and my web application works correctly now. I can see and edit tables and records.